# Unnecessary operations in view layer when observed object changes

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Suppose that you listen for changes on a User object via viewmodel and observable livedata like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
viewModel.getUser().observe(this, user -> {
  // Update UI :
  // Update userNameTextView
  // Load profile image to imageView
  // Update follower count
});
}
```

As observed User changes, you update the views. The actual change on object is probably just the follower count but you act like whole user object has changed  Ex: setting the same image to imageview.

Isn't this bad practice and waste of resources? What should you do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use databinding for binding your `User` object by making it extend [BaseObservable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable) or making it's fields [ObservableField](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField)s of their corresponding data types.

You can still use `LiveData` as the data container/channel between the View & the ViewModel for re-binding the whole `User` object.

And then for partial updates, you can `notifyPropertyChanged` on the fields you've changed, here is an example:

```
private static class User extends BaseObservable {

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   @Bindable
   public String getFirstName() {
       return this.firstName;
   }

   @Bindable
   public String getLastName() {
       return this.lastName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName);
   }

}
```